# Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources"

Tags: hibernate, gwt

I have integrated gwt with Hibernate but when I creating hibernate.reveng.xml, I have an error and I couldn't entity bean class.The error mesage ;

Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources".[enter link description here][1]

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jboss.ide.eclipse.archives.core.WorkspaceChangeListener$2.visit(WorkspaceChangeListener.java:74)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:69)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:49)
at org.jboss.ide.eclipse.archives.core.WorkspaceChangeListener.resourceChanged(WorkspaceChangeListener.java:70)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager$1.run(NotificationManager.java:291)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:285)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.broadcastChanges(NotificationManager.java:149)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.broadcastPostChange(Workspace.java:395)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.checkpoint(Workspace.java:557)
at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.PerformChangeOperation$1.run(PerformChangeOperation.java:263)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.PerformChangeOperation.executeChange(PerformChangeOperation.java:306)
at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.UIPerformChangeOperation.executeChange(UIPerformChangeOperation.java:92)
at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.PerformChangeOperation.run(PerformChangeOperation.java:218)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.run(WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.java:87)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```

Answer (score 0):

The topic of this question should better be something like:
*NullPointerException from org.jboss.ide.eclipse.archives.core.WorkspaceChangeListener (Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources".*

I am using:

- *JBoss Developer Studio (Core Features) 7.0.1.GA-v20130930-2238-B7  com.jboss.jbds.product.feature.feature.group    JBoss by Red Hat*

  - (see Eclipse->Help->About->Installation Details->Installed Software)
- *JBossTools Archives Core Plugin 3.4.100.Final-v20130717-0846-B106 (org.jboss.ide.eclipse.archives.core)*

  - (see Eclipse->Help->About->Installation Details->Plug-ins)

I found no final answer, but some points to narrow down the cause a little bit (**uninstalling JBOSS Dev Tools** in Eclipse may likely solve it if they are not needed):

- there had been a similar bugs fixed, but without further explanation what could have caused it:

  - 2009: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-3538?_sscc=t
  - 2007: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-1199?_sscc=t
- 2008: here we have some more (plugin-code-related) developer hints: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-2746?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:changehistory-tabpanel&_sscc=t

  - *forgot to set component*
  - *forgot to close*
  - *NPE when resource = workspace root*
- some of my related exceptions (that seem not to be the cause, but a "problem trigger"):

  - *AutoBuildJob.doBuild*-triggered

    ```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.ide.eclipse.archives.core.WorkspaceChangeListener$2.visit(WorkspaceChangeListener.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:49)
    at org.jboss.ide.eclipse.archives.core.WorkspaceChangeListener.resourceChanged(WorkspaceChangeListener.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager$1.run(NotificationManager.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.broadcastChanges(NotificationManager.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.broadcastPostChange(Workspace.java:396)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.endOperation(Workspace.java:1531)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
    ```
  - *JavaScriptPreferencesManager.createSuspendOnException*-triggered

    ```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.ide.eclipse.archives.core.WorkspaceChangeListener$2.visit(WorkspaceChangeListener.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:49)
    at org.jboss.ide.eclipse.archives.core.WorkspaceChangeListener.resourceChanged(WorkspaceChangeListener.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager$1.run(NotificationManager.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.broadcastChanges(NotificationManager.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.broadcastPostChange(Workspace.java:396)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.endOperation(Workspace.java:1531)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2354)
    at org.eclipse.debug.core.model.Breakpoint.run(Breakpoint.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.debug.internal.core.breakpoints.JavaScriptExceptionBreakpoint.<init>(JavaScriptExceptionBreakpoint.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.debug.internal.core.JavaScriptPreferencesManager.createSuspendOnException(JavaScriptPreferencesManager.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.debug.internal.core.JavaScriptPreferencesManager.access$2(JavaScriptPreferencesManager.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.debug.internal.core.JavaScriptPreferencesManager$StartJob.run(JavaScriptPreferencesManager.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
    ```
  - *DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch*-related/triggered

    ```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.ide.eclipse.archives.core.WorkspaceChangeListener$2.visit(WorkspaceChangeListener.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:49)
    at org.jboss.ide.eclipse.archives.core.WorkspaceChangeListener.resourceChanged(WorkspaceChangeListener.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager$1.run(NotificationManager.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.broadcastChanges(NotificationManager.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.broadcastPostChange(Workspace.java:396)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.endOperation(Workspace.java:1531)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.buildInternal(Workspace.java:532)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.build(Workspace.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:830)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:707)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1222)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
    ```
  - ...`InternalWorkspaceJob.run`...
  - ...`at org.jboss.tools.common.model.filesystems.impl.EclipseFileBodySource.write`...
  - ...